# definir una funcion de un objeto en typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, typescript, ionic2

Buen día, soy nuevo en *Typescript* y quisiera saber cómo puedo pasar mi código JavaScript a Typescript, ya que estoy reescribiendo mi código en Angular 2.

Ejemplo:

```
var o = geotab.addin.addinangular= function () {
    'use strict';
    return {
        ...
```

En este caso, `geotab` es un objeto que se define al subir el archivo JavaScript a la plataforma *GEOTAB*, y su atributo `addin` contiene una función de inicialización llamada `addinangular`. Es decir necesito poder definir una función al objeto `geotab.addin` en Typescript con esta estructura: `geotab.addin.funcion()`.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún error? Si tienes un código JavaScript deberías poder ejecutarlo sin ningún inconveniente, ya que Typescript **es un superset** de JavaScript; es decir, es una *extensión* del lenguaje.

Comment: Si error TS2304: Cannot find name 'geotab'., Me dice que ese objeto no esta definido, por lo tanto no puedo compilar el proyecto con "ng build --prod " para que me genere la carpeta dist que es la que subiré a la plataforma.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript es un lenguaje de programación superpuesto a Javascript, por lo que todo el código escrito en Javascript es válido en Typescript. Pero además, controla los *tipos* para reforzar el código y evitar que aparezcan errores en ejecución cuidando que al escribir el código se respeten los valores de las variables.

El problema viene que para ello necesita un archivo en el que se definan los tipos de la variable. Normalmente los paquetes instalados por *NPM* ya añaden estos tipos a tu proyecto. Si geotab dispone de un paquete en *NPM*, instálalo e insértalo en tu código con `import ... from 'geotab';` en lugar de añadir la librería al index.html.

Si no está la librería en *NPM* o no dispone de los *typings*, deberás declararlos manualmente añadiendo al inicio del fichero la siguiente línea:

```
declare var geotab: any;
```